# How to implement minikanren 'appendo' in J/APL?

Tags: arrays, logic, j, minikanren

I've been trying hard to implement Minikanren in J,but after making good progress up to lazy streams, conjunction, disjunction, and equivalence constraints, I am now completely stuck on the `appendo` relation.

Specifically, I'd like help (code, books, documents, etc.) on how to implement something like `appendo` with J/APL conjunctions/operators since those only allow 2 arguments (4 if yielding a value type).

[core implementation](https://github.com/Rscho314/J_microkanren/blob/master/microkanren.ijs)

[attempts at appendo](https://github.com/Rscho314/J_microkanren/blob/master/test/microkanren_test_programs.ijs)

Thanks!

Comment: I think it will be greatly beneficial if you'd share your recently published [paper](http://minikanren.org/workshop/2020/minikanren-2020-paper2.pdf) and [reference implementation](https://github.com/Rscho314/mk) as an answer. I wanted to do that myself, but then realized that you are its author :) Great job!

Comment: @9214 Hi and thanks! Although the preprint shows basic unification tasks, MicroKanren in J is not completely solved yet. In particular, making ternary (and more) relations is not supported yet. I am hard at work to make that (and more) happen soon, though. Stay tuned!